# Scrape Table With Watir without classes or ids

Tags: ruby, watir, scrape

I did not want to bother you, but I could not solve the problem :/

I'm making a scrap to a web page and this page does not have many classes or ids in its structure.

I leave an extract of the html:

```
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-left:2px solid white;">
                        <ul  class="listCarro" >
                            <li class="all">
                                <a href="javascript:searchMarcaAutosModeloDetalle('0','Todos','')">
                                    Todos
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="javascript:searchMarcaAutosModeloDetalle('0','Todos','')">

                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" style="border-right:2px solid white;">
                        <a href="javascript:searchMarcaAutosModeloDetalle('0','Todos','')">

                        </a>
                    </td>               
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="border-left:2px solid white;">
                        <ul  class="listCarro" >
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="javascript:searchMarcaAutosModeloDetalle('854','MAZDA 6 2.0 DOHC','(2002   - 2010  )')">
                                    MAZDA 6 2.0 DOHC
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="javascript:searchMarcaAutosModeloDetalle('854','MAZDA 6 2.0 DOHC','(2002   - 2010  )')">
                            LFDE
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" style="border-right:2px solid white;">
                        <a href="javascript:searchMarcaAutosModeloDetalle('854','MAZDA 6 2.0 DOHC','(2002   - 2010  )')">
                            (2002   - 2010  )
                        </a>
                    </td>               
                </tr>
```

When i use:

```
 browser.tr.as do |b|
         puts b.text.strip
 end
```

Only show me "Todos" and the following does not show them. It is difficult for me to do it since it does not contain so many classes.

Any ideas? Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience.

Regards.

Comment: What are you trying to get or do with the table?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I want to get the data, the table goes down, it's long. The problem is that the code I use only takes me to the first row.

Greetings.

Comment: Do you want all the text in the table or are you specifically targeting links?

Comment: I wish I could have them all sorted, just as there are columns without data, then I want to add those "without data".

Comment: Maybe try `browser.table.as.map(&:text)`? Sorry, I'm still having a hard time knowing exactly what you need. Giving the specific out you except for the sample table might help.